# how to used index with *ngFor in angular 2, 4, 5

Tags: html, css, angular, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngfor

if you are using angular 2, 4/5** you can't used $index directly, for using index you need to define first

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">{{item}} - {{i}}</li>
```

> {{i}} is the index of items

but in **angular 1.x** you can used index like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="let item of items>{{item}} - {{$index}}</li>
```

Comment: if you are using angular 2 than fist one is correct syntax

Answer (score 2):

if you are using angular 2+ then you should do like this for getting index , so in angular 2 onwards you don't have `ng-repeat` it replaced by `*ngFor`

```
<li *ngFor="let user of userObservable | async as users; 
                         index as i; ">
   {{i}}/{{users.length}}. {{user}}
</li>
```

or

```
<li *ngFor="let user of userObservable | async as users; 
                         let i = index; ">
   {{i}}/{{users.length}}. {{user}}
</li>
```

From the doc : [NgForOf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)